# « Faire honneur à », « être digne de », « être à la hauteur de » ou « être en accord avec »?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Le nom de ton bar est *La variété* et le personnel est composé exclusivement de jeunes âgés entre 18 et 20 ans. Ce serait bien, à mon avis, que le bar

…fasse honneur au nom qu’il porte en donnant la même représentation à toutes les tranches d’âges, du moins que d’autres tranches soient représentées.

…soit digne du nom qu’il porte en donnant la même visibilité à toutes les tranches d’âges, du moins que d’autres tranches soient représentées.

…soit à la hauteur du nom qu’il porte et cela en offrant à chaque tranche d’âge la même représentation, du moins que d’autres tranches soient représentées.

…soit en accord avec la vocation qu’il se propose, en référence au nom qu’il porte.

Ou autre formulation ?

Edit:

Une réponse serait appréciée!

Comment: La meilleure formulation est, pour moi, "...soit en accord avec le nom qu'il porte, en ce qui concerne la représentation des tranches d'âge".

Comment: @GrégoireC Si tu es là stp. verse ton commentaire en réponse et on pourra retirer le community wiki qui le reprend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le nom de ton bar est « La variété » et le personnel est composé exclusivement de jeunes âgés entre 18 et 20 ans. Ce serait bien, à mon avis, que tu joigne le geste à la parole en offrant à chaque tranche d’âge la même représentation, ou du moins en représentant d'autres tranches.

Answer (score 1):

La meilleure formulation est, pour moi :

> ...soit en accord avec le nom qu'il porte, en ce qui concerne la
> représentation des tranches d'âge. [ [Grégoire C.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/50966/faire-honneur-%C3%A0-%C3%AAtre-digne-de-%C3%AAtre-%C3%A0-la-hauteur-de-ou-%C3%AAtre-en-ac/51889#comment105793_50966) ]

Answer (score 0):

> ...soit [*représentatif*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9R1935) de ce nom en employant des gens de tous les
> âges.

Comme un échantillon serait représentatif, ici de toutes les classes d'âges.